# I use the getStaticProps function, the props change every time the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am a beginner learning nextjs.

By using the getStaticProps function, I know that I run data fetching once at build time and that the values ​​are static.

However, I noticed that the props change every time the page is refreshed in the following situations:

```
const TestPage = ({ number }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Return Number</h1>
      <span>{number}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps = () => {
  return {
    props: {
      number: Math.random(),
    },
  };
};

export default TestPage;
```

The result of the Math.random() function must be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the function `getStaticProps` will run once at build time. The reason why the value for `Math.random()` prop changes is because you are currently in development.

As per the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development), `In development (next dev), getStaticProps will be called on every request.`. When you refresh the page, a new request is sent (since you're in development), hence, the value is changed.

Comment: What about a production, if am getting any data from server from api call and want to refresh the page props with update props. ?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq, you have to use the getServerSideProps function for that. You may refer here https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#:~:text=does%20getServerSideProps%20run-,getServerSideProps,js%20sends%20an%20API%20request%20to%20the%20server%2C%20which%20runs%20getServerSideProps,-getServerSideProps. You may also use the useEffect() like in react as well.